FastAPI and Couchbase
I’m currently working on a CRUD application using FastAPI and Couchbase, but I’ve encountered a problem with the GET method—it doesn’t seem to be functioning as expected. I’ve tried debugging but haven’t been able to identify the issue. Could someone provide guidance or help me resolve this?
Here is the code:
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster, ClusterOptions
from couchbase.auth import PasswordAuthenticator
from couchbase.exceptions import DocumentNotFoundException
from couchbase.bucket import Bucket
​
class Error(BaseModel):
    description: str
    error_code: str
    error_id: int
    timestamp: str
​
class Location(BaseModel):
    coordinates: str
    location_id: int
    room_name: str
​
class MaintenanceHistory(BaseModel):
    description: str
    maintenance_date: str
    maintenance_id: int
    parts: list
​
class User(BaseModel):
    address: str
    email: str
    name: str
    phone_number: str
    user_id: int
​
class Task(BaseModel):
    scheduled_time: str
    status: str
    task_id: int
    task_type: str
    user: User
​
class Robot(BaseModel):
    robot_id: int
    model: str
    serial_number: str
    status: str
    errors: list[Error]
    locations: list[Location]
    maintenance_history: list[MaintenanceHistory]
    tasks: list[Task]
    usage_history: list
    user_settings: list
​
# FastAPI app and CORS middleware setup
app = FastAPI()
​
origins = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:5500", 
    "http://localhost:5500", 
]
​
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins, 
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"], 
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
​
# Couchbase connection setup (same as before)
cluster = Cluster('couchbases://cb.flgdpdewcbi5.cloud.couchbase.com', ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator('Robot', ‘dddddd’)))
bucket = cluster.bucket('robot_system')
collection = bucket.scope('system').collection('Robot')
​
# Endpoints (same as before)
@app.get("/robots/{robot_id}", response_model=Robot)
async def get_robot(robot_id: int):
    try:
        document = collection.get(str(robot_id))
        return document.content_as[Robot]
    except DocumentNotFoundException:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Robot not found")```


First problem - you are sing sync db call inside async endpoint function. eiver use async db methods or make endpoint function synchronous (it will be run in a threadpool)

"it doesn’t seem to be functioning as expected" - what exactly doesn't work as you expected? Do you have any error messages? Please explain the difference between current behaviour and expected.

i mean, i just want to receive a robot when i call this method. Now I dont receive anything
should i do like this:
@app.get("/robots/{robot_id}", response_model=Robot)
async def get_robot(robot_id: int):
  try:
    document = await collection.get(str(robot_id))
    return await document.content_as[Robot]
  except DocumentNotFoundException:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Robot not found")```
or what is the solution?

Hi! Adding code to comments is generally makes it very hard to read. Please update the question to include what result you'd expect, and what you are currently getting (including the full text of any error messages). Just "doesn’t seem to be functioning as expected" neans nothing.
